# Converting JSON object to HTML template

Tags: html, angular, css

I am using Angular 6 and my templates are as below.

1. Header, Left panel, Body part, footer
2. Header,Left panel, Body part, right panel, footer
3. Header, body part, footer

Since, I have so many templates, I wanted to make it JSON driven instead of just hardcoding html part.

The JSON file will look like,

```
{
   "horizontal" : [
     {
      width : 20%,
      height: 100%
     },
     {
      width : 80%,
      height: 100%,
      {
       "vertical" : [
         {
           width : 80%,
           height: 60%
         },
         {
           width : 80%,
           height: 40%
         }
       ]
      }
     }
   ],
 }
```

Here, the page gets divided into left panel(20% width) and body(80%) and then body gets divided into vertically like 60% top and 20% bottom.

Is there any way to make this JSON into HTML?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am new to HTML. I am basically a backend developer and trying to make it dynamic very fist time. I am looking for something like dynamic form, but not sure abt this conversion.

Comment: Have you heard about Bootstrap toolkit grid system, it would help https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/

Comment: Look at flex grid system, there is a good tutorial (paid here) flexbox.io and also a free skeleton like bootstrap: flexboxgrid.com

Comment: if it helps, look for templating engines like Mustache.js, handlebars etc.
Refer : https://mustache.github.io/
https://handlebarsjs.com/
it will create a template for you, and everytime you can change according to different objects data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this question is too broad, I were/am a back end guy too, and wen't through many ideas before landing, so I decided to post an answer and share my experience.

My intention with this is to show how simple, and with how little code, one can create something reusable and easy to maintain.

---

Instead of convert styles from a JSON to HTML, use what is meant for that, CSS, and here is a few samples how to manage many templates with a small style guide, and get one of the best features of all, performance.

With one CSS, making using Flexbox, and the given logic for your different templates, it could look like this.

Sample 1 (with CSS notes)

```css
html, body, .container {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.container, main {
  display: flex;           /* make children flex items */
  flex-direction: column;  /* default flow is row */
}

header, footer {           /* flex column item will by default fill parent's width */
                           /* height is controlled by content */
}

.wrapper {                 
  flex: 1;                 /* fill remaining height (flex column item) */
  display: flex;
}
 
aside {                    /* flex row item will by default fill parent's height */
  flex-basis: 20%;         /* set width (flex column item) */
}

main {
  flex: 1;                 /* fill remaining width (flex row item) */
}

section {
  flex-basis: 60%;         /* set height (flex column item) */
}

section + section {        /* target the 2nd section */
  flex-basis: 40%;
}


/* for demo purpose */
header, footer, aside, section {
  border: 1px dotted gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>Header</header>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <aside>Aside</aside>
    <main>
      <section>Section</section>
      <section>Section</section>
    </main>
  </div>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Sample 2

```css
html, body, .container {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.container, main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header, footer {
}

.wrapper {                 
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}
 
aside {
  flex-basis: 20%;
}

main {
  flex: 1;
}

section {
  flex-basis: 60%;
}

section + section {
  flex-basis: 40%;
}


header, footer, aside, section {
  border: 1px dotted gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>Header</header>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <aside>Aside</aside>
    <main>
      <section>Section</section>
      <section>Section</section>
    </main>
    <aside>Aside</aside>
  </div>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Sample 3

```css
html, body, .container {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.container, main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header, footer {
}

.wrapper {                 
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}
 
aside {
  flex-basis: 20%;
}

main {
  flex: 1;
}

section {
  flex-basis: 60%;
}

section + section {
  flex-basis: 40%;
}


header, footer, aside, section {
  border: 1px dotted gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>Header</header>
  <main>
    <section>Section</section>
    <section>Section</section>
  </main>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</div>
```

---

Or for a given template, using different CSS (only show 1 and 3 here, as 2 will be the same as the above)

Sample 1

```css
html, body, .container {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.container, main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header, footer {
}

.wrapper {                 
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}
 
aside {
  flex-basis: 20%;
}

main + aside {             /* target the 2nd/right aside */
  display: none;
}

main {
  flex: 1;
}

section {
  flex-basis: 60%;
}

section + section {
  flex-basis: 40%;
}


/* for demo purpose */
header, footer, aside, section {
  border: 1px dotted gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>Header</header>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <aside>Aside</aside>
    <main>
      <section>Section</section>
      <section>Section</section>
    </main>
    <aside>Aside</aside>
  </div>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Sample 3

```css
html, body, .container {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.container, main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header, footer {
}

.wrapper {                 
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}
 
aside {
  display: none;
}

main {
  flex: 1;
}

section {
  flex-basis: 60%;
}

section + section {
  flex-basis: 40%;
}


/* for demo purpose */
header, footer, aside, section {
  border: 1px dotted gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>Header</header>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <aside>Aside</aside>
    <main>
      <section>Section</section>
      <section>Section</section>
    </main>
    <aside>Aside</aside>
  </div>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. I dont want to hard code 20% or so since it will be DB driven. So, I can not go with hard coding in CSS and I want this also to be dynamic.

Comment: @user1578872 My answer doesn't prevent that, it just shows how to make use of built-in tech, and e.g. the CSS I provided is no more difficult to generate dynamically than your JSON file sample.

Comment: I tried setting the values dynamically like,  <section [ngClass]="{'width':section.width}">, but it doesnt work. Not sure how to dynamically pass the % value?

Comment: @user1578872 I don't know Angularjs so can't help you with that part, though it being a very specific issue, please post it as a new question, with more details and you'll for sure get an answer.